# TextView upside down in Android when set support RTL and Device in Hebrew Language

Tags: android, hebrew

I have some issue with textview in my application
when I set in Manifest Support:rtl true  and when I install the application in device with hebrew language in interface my textview is upside down 
I have some screenshot for this
first screen shot [image]

if you can look the title "lubcnet" which marked in red  textview is upside down 
I need that show is "netclub"
I add the xml file which include the texviews.

```
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
    android:textDirection="rtl"
    android:text="@string/Net"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/textPrimaryColor"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:id="@+id/Net"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/animText"
    android:text="@string/C"
    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
    android:textDirection="rtl"
    android:gravity="end"

    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/animl"
    android:textSize="30sp"

    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/lub"
    android:text="@string/Lub"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:textDirection="rtl"
    android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/textPrimaryColor"
    android:textSize="25sp"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options:
1.Change your layout to be RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout and set the direction using "layout_leftOf" etc

### Edit 1

Something like that:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Net"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:text="@string/Net"
        android:textColor="@color/textPrimaryColor"
        android:textDirection="rtl"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/animText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Net"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:text="@string/C"
        android:textColor="@color/animl"
        android:textDirection="rtl"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"

        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lub"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/animText"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:text="@string/Lub"
        android:textColor="@color/textPrimaryColor"
        android:textDirection="rtl"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

2.Change your layout order to be:

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_conten1t"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/lub"
android:text="@string/Lub"
android:gravity="end"
android:textDirection="rtl"
android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textColor="@color/textPrimaryColor"
android:textSize="25sp"/>

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/animText"
android:text="@string/C"
android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
android:textDirection="rtl"
android:gravity="end"

android:textStyle="bold"
android:textColor="@color/animl"
android:textSize="30sp"

/>

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="end"
android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
android:textDirection="rtl"
android:text="@string/Net"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textColor="@color/textPrimaryColor"
android:textSize="25sp"
android:id="@+id/Net"
/>
```

Comment: i try make the second way but if i change the device language this make  me problem again i try to check the first way u can explain the first way?

Comment: Updated an example, you can play with it

Comment: thank you i find other way for support rtl in the linearlayout xml i wiil set android:layoutdirecation:ltr and this work like a charm :]